# Can we print multiple insets along with a main map within a single pdf(image would also do) using ARCGIS Export Map Specification?

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, export-to-pdf, insets

Generalized problem statement :  I want to print US geography(with some feature layers) on to a pdf. And I am making use of ARCGIS export map specification in which i pass the webmapasjson with a relevant template.    This gets the work done.

I am looking for an extra bit wherein I want to print ALASKA,HAWAI,Puerto Rico in separate insets within the same pdf . Now what i understand is that ,to print a webmap we need a webmapasjson which would essentially be representing one view.  This webmapasjson would bind to WebmapFrame specified in the layout file.  Since i am looking to have multiple insets ,i need to manage multiple webmapasjson.  Now the thing i havent been able to crack is that how can i export the map with these multiple insets and one main map within the same pdf.  I am making use of arcpy.mp.ConvertWebMapToArcgiSProject function which accepts only one webmapasjson along with a layout.

Regards,

Rohit Bhardwaj

I am looking to override the arcpy.mp.ConvertWebMapToArcgiSProject so as to make it accept multiple webmapasjson and also each of them binds to respective webmapframe in layout file(.pagx) file.so far that hasnt been successful.